# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You must provide your own Dockerfile when using a custom runtime

Tags: r, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I am trying to schedule an R job on Google Cloud using App Engine. I am following the article

https://code.markedmondson.me/4-ways-schedule-r-scripts-on-google-cloud-platform/

However, when I try to deploy the app using `gcloud app deploy --project shiny-demo` I get the following error

```
Enabling service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] on project [shiny-demo]...
Waiting for async operation operations/acf.33c5e6da-6f9e-4e66-b7d3-f0611eddc0ce to complete...
Operation finished successfully. The following command can describe the Operation details:
 gcloud services operations describe operations/tmo-acf.33c5e6da-6f9e-4e66-b7d3-f0611eddc0ce
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You must provide your own Dockerfile when using a custom runtime. Otherwise provide a "runtime" field with one of the supported runtimes.
```

I do have a Dockerfile in the same folder as my yaml file, however somehow it does not recognize the Dockerfile. Below is my yaml file:

```yaml
# app.yaml file
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  GCS_AUTH_FILE: authkey.json
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# DOCKER
FROM trestletech/plumber
LABEL maintainer="mark"
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get -y update \
 && apt-get install -y libcairo2-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    make \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    zlib1g-dev
RUN ["install2.r", "-r 'https://cloud.r-project.org'", "readr", "googleCloudStorageR", "bigrquery", "Rcpp", "digest", "crayon", "withr", "mime", "R6", "jsonlite", "xtable", "magrittr", "httr", "curl", "testthat", "devtools", "hms", "shiny", "httpuv", "memoise", "htmltools", "openssl", "tibble", "remotes"]
RUN ["installGithub.r", "MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR@7917351", "hadley/rlang@ff87439"]
WORKDIR /payload/
COPY [".", "./"]

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["R", "-e", "pr <- plumber::plumb(commandArgs()[4]); pr$run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)"]
CMD ["myscript.R"]
```

I am a bit new to Docker.

Adding the picture for folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your Dockerfile name is `Dockerfile` (first letter uppercase)?

Windows sometimes saves the file internally as `.txt`.

> [A Dockerfile must be created with no extension.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#basic-syntax) To do this in Windows,
>   create the file with your editor of choice, then save it with the
>   notation "Dockerfile" (including the quotes).

Is your Dockefile in the [right path](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#naming_and_locating_the_dockerfile) at the same level as the `app.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure of that.I have updated the folder structure for your reference

Comment: Could you check that your `Dockerfile` has [no extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#basic-syntax)?

Comment: This would be one of the stupidest mistake that I might have made. Dockerfile was saved with the extension .txt. I removed it worked. Thanks a lot for the help. Would you know anything about the package rga and its authentication flow

Comment: Feel free to create another question with the corresponding tags!